# Error in rest test class : Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest

I have a class :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/commande')
global with sharing class RESTCommande  {

@HttpGet
global static String getCodeCommande() {
    String retour;
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String eventId = req.params.get('eventId');
    Id clientId = req.params.get('clientId');
    Date dateCommande = Date.valueOf(req.params.get('dateCommande'));
    Event commandeWeb = new Event();

    RecordType rtRDVPLP = [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'RDVPLP'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];

    RecordType rtWeb = [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'Web'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];

    Contact currentClient = [SELECT Id, Name, Conseillere__c, IdClientWeb__c FROM Contact WHERE IdClientWeb__c =:clientId];

    if(eventId == null || eventId == ''){
        try {
            insert new Commande__c(Conseill_re__c = currentClient.Conseillere__c, RecordTypeId = rtWeb.Id, Date_de_commande__c = dateCommande, Type_de_commande__c='Web');

        } catch (DMLException e) {
            //System.debug('#### ' + e);
            throw e;
        }

    }
    else{
        commandeWeb = [SELECT Id, Tech_Id_Commande__c, WhatId FROM Event WHERE Id=:eventId];

        if(commandeWeb.Tech_Id_Commande__c == null){
            Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
            params.put('EventId', eventId);
            params.put('ConseillereId', commandeWeb.WhatId);//ExtranetV2_Utils.currentConseillere.Id);

            Flow.Interview.CreationCommandeEtPanierDepuisRDVPLP flow = new Flow.Interview.CreationCommandeEtPanierDepuisRDVPLP(params);
            flow.start();

            String commandeId = (String) flow.getVariableValue('commandeId');
            //String panierId = (String) flow.getVariableValue('panierId');

            try {
                commandeWeb.Tech_Id_Commande__c =commandeId;
                update commandeWeb;
            } catch (DMLException e) {
                //System.debug('#### ' + e);

                throw e;
            }

        }
        else if(commandeWeb == null){
            retour = 'Erreur : l\'Id de l\'événement est null ou incorrect';
        }
        else{ 
            retour = commandeWeb.Tech_Id_Commande__c; //retourne null
        }

    }

    return retour;

}
```

When I try my test class, I get the error :

> System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

at the line `Date dateCommande = Date.valueOf(req.params.get('dateCommande'));`

Hereis my test class :

```
@isTest
private class RESTCommandeTest {

@isTest static void getCodeCommande_Test() {
    Account conseillere = new Account(FirstName = 'test',
                                      LastName = 'test',
                                      Statut_Activitee__c = 'Responsable réseau (AU)',
                                      RecordTypeId = triggerCandidateTools.retrievePersonAccountRecordTypeId(),
                                      Pays__c = 'France (FRA)');
    insert conseillere;
    Contact hotesse = new Contact(Firstname = 'test',Lastname = 'test', Salutation = 'Madame',
                                    Adresse_1_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Adresse_2_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Adresse3_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Code_postal_client__c = '44000',
                                    Ville_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Email = 'mail@mail.com',
                                    IdClientWeb__c = '123'
                                    );
    insert hotesse;
    Event ev = new Event(StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         EndDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         Subject = 'Appel',
                         WhoId = hotesse.Id,
                         WhatId = conseillere.Id);
    insert ev;
    Date dateCommande = Date.valueOf('2016-06-06');     

    RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
    req.requestURI = 'https://cs86.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/commande?eventId=' + ev.Id + '&clientId=' + hotesse.IdClientWeb__c
                        + '&dateCommande=' + dateCommande;  
    req.httpMethod = 'GET';

    RestContext.request = req;

    RecordType rt = [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'Autre type'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];
    Commande__c comm = new Commande__c(Date_heure_de_d_but_RDVPLP__c = Datetime.now(),
                                        Date_heure_de_fin_RDVPLP__c = Datetime.now(),
                                        H_tesse__c = hotesse.Id,
                                        RecordTypeId = rt.Id,
                                        Conseill_re__c = conseillere.Id);
    insert comm;
    String code = RESTCommande.getCodeCommande();

}
```

(the error indicates the line `String code = RESTCommande.getCodeCommande();` of the test class)

Thank you, and sorry for all the code block...

Comment: Probably not the cause of this problem, but if you choose to build the URL by string concatenation, make sure you URL encode every parameter that could contain spaces or slashes etc e.g.  `EncodingUtil.urlEncode(String.valueOf(dateCommande), 'UTF-8')` as otherwise the URL will not be parsed correctly.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work either. How can I build an url if not by concatenation ?

Comment: It looks like the `params` map is not being populated, i suspect that gets deserialised when you make the request for real, but you are calling `RESTCommande.getCodeCommande()` directly so would assume the deserialisation doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is coming because

```
req.params.get('dateCommande')
```

is returning null. And

```
Date.valueOf(req.params.get('dateCommande'));
```

which ultimately means

```
 Date.valueOf(null);
```

will raise exception as Date.valueOf function can not accept 'null' as argument.

Use `RestRequest.addparameter(parametername,paramatervalue)` 
Method to set parameters in test class.

Adding test class code with corrections:

```
@isTest
private class RESTCommandeTest {

@isTest static void getCodeCommande_Test() {
    Account conseillere = new Account(FirstName = 'test',
                                      LastName = 'test',
                                      Statut_Activitee__c = 'Responsable réseau (AU)',
                                      RecordTypeId = triggerCandidateTools.retrievePersonAccountRecordTypeId(),
                                      Pays__c = 'France (FRA)');
    insert conseillere;
    Contact hotesse = new Contact(Firstname = 'test',Lastname = 'test', Salutation = 'Madame',
                                    Adresse_1_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Adresse_2_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Adresse3_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Code_postal_client__c = '44000',
                                    Ville_client__c = 'aaa',
                                    Email = 'mail@mail.com',
                                    IdClientWeb__c = '123'
                                    );
    insert hotesse;
    Event ev = new Event(StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         EndDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         Subject = 'Appel',
                         WhoId = hotesse.Id,
                         WhatId = conseillere.Id);
    insert ev;
    Date dateCommande = Date.valueOf('2016-06-06');     

    RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
    req.requestURI = 'https://cs86.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/commande';
    req.addParameter('eventId',''+ev.Id);
    req.addParameter('clientId',''+hotesse.IdClientWeb__c);
    req.addParameter('dateCommande',''+dateCommande);   
    req.httpMethod = 'GET';

    RestContext.request = req;

    RecordType rt = [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'Autre type'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];
    Commande__c comm = new Commande__c(Date_heure_de_d_but_RDVPLP__c = Datetime.now(),
                                        Date_heure_de_fin_RDVPLP__c = Datetime.now(),
                                        H_tesse__c = hotesse.Id,
                                        RecordTypeId = rt.Id,
                                        Conseill_re__c = conseillere.Id);
    insert comm;
    String code = RESTCommande.getCodeCommande();

}
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Mukesh Verma for the explanation ! But I stille don't see why `dateCommande` is null, since in my test class I put a value in the url in the place where `dateCommande` is...

Comment: the params map is not getting populated...

Comment: @Phil Hawthorn I add `params.put('dateComm', dateCommande);` in the RESTCommande class, but I still get the error...

Comment: Improved answer. req. addparameter() will make it work.

Comment: It does not work too... Or maybe I'm not putting it in the right place ...

Comment: @dou: Please see revised class code with corrections. I was expecting parameters to be set in same way. I feel this will work.